# Landing Page for Age check in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have built a marketing site for an alcohol brand and I need to check the user's age by adding a landing page before they can enter the main site. What is the best way to tackle the form, submit and validation functionality inside my existing rails app?

Should I just create a raw html form and use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `before_action` to `ApplicationController` that checks if the verification has already taken place (i.e. if it is stored in a cookie, then check for the cookie, etc):

```
class ApplicationController

  before_action :check_age

  def check_age
   # check if the user has already confirmed their age.
  end

  ...

end
```

If it doesn't find this, then redirect the user to a controller action that renders a page with the age check form (i.e. `AgeVerificationController#new`)

Upon submit, set the cookie (or whatever you are doing to store this data), and redirect the user back to the page they were intending to visit (or kick them off the site if they say they are under age!)

You will need to include a `skip_before_action` on the controller you are using to handle the rendering and submission of the form, i.e.

```
class AgeVerificationController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :check_age

...

end`
```

Using `before_action` is sometimes a bit of an anti-pattern if you start using it to do a lot of complex stuff, but in this case it is a fairly simple way of doing what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

even if you use javascript,you will need to **store** the age of the guest to help him out next time for a better user experience.So i will suggest you to save it along with the ip-address to recognise the guest,if you are not storing a unique parameter for login(such as email,mobile number etc).
Once you have the table ready to store this details...you have many options such as:-

1. **first option** is to that,before submit get the age of guest using jquery validation and pass it to the controller using form and store it.Use ajax for form submission so that 
   you can validate other elements as well
2. **second option** is to let the user visit the page and show a modal window popup in the middle,after five seconds when page has loaded by using [settimeout](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/) to call ajax which in turn will call a controller method to render js file which will call a modal such as `$(".myModal").show();` or render your own view to get user details such as:

   `$('#myModal').find('.modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'users/get_details')) %>");
    $('#myModal').modal();`